# in codeigniter how can i get uri segments by name?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, parameters, uri

I have the latest codeigniter version, and was wondering how can i get the segments in a url by their parameter name.  For instance, here is a sample url:

```
www.somewebsitedomain.com/param1=something/param2=somethingelse/
```

now lets say i want to get the value for 'param1', which is 'something', how would i do so using the uri class?

Because by default the uri class only gets segments by number, or the order in which they appear, but i want to get segments by the parameter name in that segment.  Or in general just get the parameter value.  Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)` which will give something like the following

```
[array]
 (
'name' => 'joe'
'location'  => 'UK'
'gender'    => 'male'
)
```

Then just just the param name you would like.

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: For the `uri_to_assoc()` method to work, the URI must be in the following format: `domain.tld/key/value/key2/value2/key3/value3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually put them as GET vars and use the [Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html):

```
$param = $this->input->get('param1'); // something
```

or you can do:

```
$params = $this->input->get(); // array('param1' => 'something', 'param2' => 'somethingelse')
```

to get all the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking, but in many applications, URLs follow the form www.domain.com/controller/method/key1/value1/key2/value2. So I decided to extend the CI_URI class to return the value of any "key".

If you put this in your application/core folder, in a file named, MY_URI.php, it extends the built-in URI class:

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    /* call parent constructor */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /* return value of the URI segment
       which immediately follows the named segment */
    function getNamed($str=NULL) {

        $key = array_search($str, $this->segments);

        if ($key && isset($this->segments[$key+1])) {
            return $this->segments[$key+1];
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Then if your URLs are in the form

```
www.somewebsitedomain.com/param1/something/param2/somethingelse/
```

you can call this function as follows:

`$this->uri->getNamed('param1)` - returns "something"

`$this->uri->getNamed('param2)` - returns "somethingelse"